# Margins of header apa6 document class

Tags: header-footer, margins, geometry, apa6

I can modify the margins of the body of an `apa6` class document by reloading the geometry package:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=15mm,
 right=15mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
```

But the header of every page is badly aligned:
[image]

how can I set a correct margin (flushing it to the right) of the page numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would need to manually typeset the layout of the document. If you use the `\documentclass[a4paper, noextraspace, man, natbib, 12pt]{apa6}` options on the `apa6` class header, you should have all that you need to the layout of a typical APA style manuscript.

You can use the `\shorttitle{}` to make the running head on each page after establishing your main title.

Therefore, your document may look something like

```
\documentclass[a4paper, noextraspace,man,natbib,12pt]{apa6}

%Insert packages you might like to load

\title{}
\shorttitle{} %For Running Head
\author{}
\affiliation{}

\begin{document}

%Insert the body of text here

\end{document}
```

The `apa6` class should automatically load the required formatting to your paper without having to manually set it across the document.

Comment: And how would I do this if I need specific margins? Also, I am not using the manuscript option, but the document option

Comment: If you are writing a standard APA manuscript, you should just use the `man` option. Are you referring to specific margins outside of the standard ones provided by the APA6 class?

Comment: Yes, I want different margins, not in the standard APA norm

Comment: Are you using a standard `apa6` class or `article` class? Using the package `fancyhdr` might help if you are using the `article` class. (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Headers_and_footers)

Comment: The apa6 class, as explained in the question.